# Connect between the pods in the same namespace

Tags: kubernetes

I need to connect between pod-1 and pod-2 in the same namespace. I want to test mutlicast using `netcat`.

I tried to listen on one pod and connect to that from the other pod using the pod-1 IP but that doesn't work. I even tried tomcat7.test-web-dev and that doesn't work either. Ping doesn't respond either.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tomcat7
  namespace: test-web-dev
spec:
  selector:
    app: tomcat7 # Metadata label of the deployemnt pod template or pod metadata label
  ports:
    - name: port-1234 
      protocol: TCP
      port: 1234
      targetPort: 1234
    - name: port-1234 
      protocol: UDP
      port: 1234
      targetPort: 1234
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try connecting to:

```
<clusterip>.<namespace>.pod.cluster.local
```

or

```
<clusterip>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local
```

but yes, in general, it is a pain to setup these things depending on your k8s deployment.

You can also enter the client pod using kubectl and try pinging the server one on different addresses until success.

```
kubectl exec --stdin --tty <client-pod-name> -- /bin/bash
```

Comment: doesn't work. I'm trying to ping second pod it from first pod. Name or service not known error.

`10.0.0.249.namespace1.pod-name.cluster.local` and `10.0.0.249.namespace1.svc.cluster.local` both fails

Comment: don't use the ip as it is ephemeral, you need to use the name of the cluster ip for example tomcat7

Comment: how do I get the name of the cluster IP?

Comment: it is the name you define in the service yaml
`apiVersion: v1`
`kind: Service`
`metadata:`
  `name: tomcat7`

Comment: Okay that works for your second version but that connects through service and does round robin.  The first version still doesn't work which is `tomcat7.namespace1.podname####.cluster.local`. Is something wrong here?

Comment: in the sepc the pod name is `tomcat7` as well. So i even tried `tomcat7.namespace1.tomcat7.cluster.local`

Comment: I want direct connect to the other pod

Comment: this is the most direct connection you will get with Kubernetes ... it is not a round-robin sort of thing but it is driven by the architecture of Kubernetes itself. By definition, you cannot connect two pods without first assigning services to them

Comment: Is your pod is creating using `kind: Pod` or any other kind?

Comment: I don't specify the `kind: Pod` since its part of a deployment. The template section has the pod details but without `kind`

Answer (score 0):

`<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local` or `<service-name>.<namespace>` works as well.